# Why I am getting null pointer exception even though there is value show when println?

Tags: java, android

This is a function of class A where i pass my value to a class name confirm to its register function.

```
private void registerOrder() {
    confirm.register(id);
}
```

This is class confirm. In this class i have plan to post data inside the server. There is no mistakes in the url. I have println this code " System.out.println("wei" + getPostDataString(postDataParams));" and i have gotten my value. But the system says null pointer. Is there any mistakes in other pats of the code?

```
 public class confirm {
 private static final String REGISTER_URL = 
 "http://192.168.43.214/apexStore2/confirm.php";

 public static void register(String id) {
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
        }
  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("product_id",params[0]);

            String result = sendPost(REGISTER_URL,data);

            return  result;
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(String.valueOf(id));
 }
 public static String sendPost(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = " ";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +                       
  Integer.toString(getPostDataString(postDataParams).getBytes().length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        System.out.println("wei" + getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        }
        else {
            response="Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) 
throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: println needs message, occurs when there is no  data to display in Log statements or SOP's. Attach a debugger and check that your value is getting or not..

Comment: Take a look at the stacktrace from NPE and see where it's thrown from.

Comment: for the debugging, should i write like this?  Log.d(getPostDataString(postDataParams), "onCreate()");

Comment: when debug using the above i get "product_id" -> "12"

Comment: You just missed to initialize your _ProgressDialog_ in _onPreExecute_ method.

Comment: should i initialize my progressdialog like this? oading = ProgressDialog.show(confirm.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);?

Comment: Yes now you have caught what you need to do.

Comment: However since my function is static, when i use confirm.this, there are error said static and non static incompatible

Comment: Yes you should also make your _ProgressDialog_ static.

Comment: when i make it static, it requires class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> to be static as well, however when i add static to class  RegisterUser it says that you cannot add static to that class. What should i add?

Answer (score 2):

You have an instance variable, which is never assigned to:

```
ProgressDialog loading;
```

and it is used in

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    loading.dismiss();     // expect NPE
}
```

Comment: when i debug, i get the value

Comment: Which value do you mean?

Comment: this one  System.out.println("wei" + getPostDataString(postDataParams));

Comment: when i debug i also get data, at public static String sendPost function

Comment: I'm referring to `loading` being null, so calling `loading.dismiss()` causes a NPE. Nothing to do with those strings.

Comment: so what value should i pass to loading?

Comment: Don't use the dismiss call and see what happens. A ProgressDialog is nice to have but not necessary for a server connection. Not sure how you could indicate a progress in this scenario anyway.

Comment: i didnt use the dismiss call and no null pointer error is shown but data is not passing to the database as well. Is there problem with my server connection?

Comment: Very likely - there are several possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I supose the null pointer exception appears when you call `confirm.register(id)`.

If you want to use a class in a static manner you need to declare it as a final class:

```
public final class confirm {...}
```

For you it should work. Nevertheless you can also solve your problem without using the final identifier by creating an instance of your class:

```
confirm conf = new confirm();
conf.register(id);
```

I also have seen that your class name begins with a lowercase letter. It is recomended to create the classes names begining with a capital letter.

If it doesn't solve your error please, pastate the error information here.

Comment: the null pointer is solve by eliminating  loading.dismiss();  from onpostexecute. However data is not passing to the database. Is there something wrong with my method?